# Does Divshot import external bootstrap template?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, divshot

Is that possible to import my bootstrap project into Divshot?

Is there any other web-based editor capable to import my HTML project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can import existing Bootstrap templates and CSS files in Divshot. Click the `+` icon in the navigator panel and select `Upload Files`.

[image: Divshot Navigator: Upload Files]

After opening your HTML page(s) in Divshot you may have to update your `<link>` stylesheet tags to make sure the paths are correct. You can do this by opening the source editor and using relative paths or you can remove the link tags and drag the stylesheets over from the navigator to the canvas. Doing so will automatically generate `<link>` tags and add them to the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy your HTML markup and CSS into the project inside Divshot. I'm pretty sure that's possible with Divshot, I know it is possible with 'Jetstrap' which is another Twitter-bootstrap visual editor.
Another one is 'Bootply' which is great for the Bootstrap 3 :)